# casperjs download file without specifying url

Tags: casperjs

Is there any way to download CSV file with casperjs without specifying download URL? I am trying to download CSV file whose URL is dynamically generated when I click the download button. So, I may not be able to use download() well under the situation.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, it's already possible using 'resource.received' event.
If you receive header like this one:

> Content-Disposition: Attachment; Filename="ExportData.csv"

The file generated can be downloaded using following event listener:

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
    if (resource.stage !== "end") {
        console.log("resource.stage !== 'end'");
        return;
    }
    if (resource.url.indexOf('ExportData.csv') > -1) {
        console.log("Downloading csv file");
        this.download(resource.url, 'ExportData.csv');
    }
});
```

Comment: what version you used?

Comment: @DiegoBorges I don't remember which version was that. However I've found that CASPER-1.1.0-DEV has this function: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for that. It is not very clean but it works :

You need to build an global array, which associates every resource.received having a filename attached.

```
fileInfos[url]= parse_filename_from_responseHeader(resource)
```

If url is the resource you want to download, try open(url) first. This will trigger the resiyrce.received event, parse the header and update the global array.

Now, before launching the `casper.download(url)`, look for `fileInfos[url]`.

You will find the filename corresponding to the url in the fileInfos array.
I can elaborate on the solution if needed, but since the question is already a few years old,

I'll wait for the next poke to elaborate.

Comment: Please elaborate the code in more details, want to check if the URL is download URL using casperjs.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible until this phantomjs issue will be solved http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=52

Comment: I know that you dont have time, and you are searching for a team to continue in project (compatibility v2.0 of PhantomJS). You have any idea of deadline?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is something like this but I know the filename that I am gonna receive:

```
this.waitForResource(function check(resource){
            res = resource;    
            // regular expression to test
            return /thefilename/.test(resource.url);
        }, function(){
            this.echo("Resource found: " + res.url);
            // download the file
            this.download(res.url, path);
        }, null, 10000);
```