# How To Automate Teamwork Backup Download

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to automate downloading the backup file created by [Teamwork](https://www.teamwork.com/). The way it works is you login, go to a page which loads a dynamically generated iframe with a src="https://tw-backup.teamwork.com/ext.cfm?backupaction=downloadLatestMySQLBackup".

I've tried getting the actual link from from the iframe, but I haven't gotten that to work. However, the truncated link I'm using seems to work if I enter it in the browser. So I'm just trying to open it directly.

Unfortunately, it just seems to hang.

**EDIT**

phantomjs --version = 1.9.8;

Getting this error:

```
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://tw-backup.teamwork.com/ext.cfm?backupa
ction=downloadLatestMySQLBackup"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Done 8 steps in 3427ms
finished
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with U
RL file:///c:/Users/Brad/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap
.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

So is the problem that I'm trying to access a different sub-domain than from where I start?

You can get a free trial of Teamwork if you're interested in this problem. And BTW, we're making good use it for project management.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://myco.teamwork.com/', function () {

    console.log("start");

    this.waitForSelector("input[name='userLogin']",
        function success() {
            this.sendKeys("input[name='userLogin']", "me@myco.org");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("input[name='userLogin']");
        });
    this.waitForSelector("input[name='password']",
        function success() {
            this.sendKeys("input[name='password']", "somePassword");
            console.log("login successful");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("input[name='password']");
            console.log("login failed");
        });

    this.thenOpen('https://tw-backup.teamwork.com/ext.cfm?backupaction=downloadLatestMySQLBackup');   

});
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors. Try to run CasperJS with `--ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Please see edits..

Comment: That "error" (Unsafe JavaScript attempt...) suggests that you're using PhantomJS 1.9.8 and not 1.9.2. [It's actually not an error, but only some string that is printed when CasperJS is exiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608391/using-phantomjs-to-embed-all-images-of-a-webpage-produces-warnings-but-works). I don't see an error in your question. How do you verify that the second page load succeeded or failed?

Comment: Right, it's 1.9.8 (typo). 

The log says, "[debug] [phantom] url changed to https://tw-backup.teamwork.com/ext.cfm?backupa
ction=downloadLatestMySQLBackup". Doesn't that mean that the page load worked?

Comment: Yes, it does, that's why I'm asking what steps come after that load and how you verify that it didn't work.

Comment: I see. That link triggers a download of the backup file. The backup is a .zip.  So obviously this is not a direct link to the actual file. But the response is the .zip, which I'm not getting. 

Putting that URL into a browser triggers the file download immediately.

Comment: Yeah, PhantomJS doesn't download files. You might be successful with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461096/casperjs-download-file-without-specifying-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally accomplished this by moving to Selenium and using the Chrome driver;The Firefox driver won't work because it pops up a save dialog.

Unfortunately, I haven't gotten this work headless. I was hoping that  HtmlUnitDriver would work. And it still may be possible, but for my purposes having the browser open is actually OK.

*Note that you need to have the Chrome [webdriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) installed.  On the MAC, you just drop it in /usr/bin. On Windows, create a folder with both the .jar and the chromedriver.ext. Then execute it with:*

```
C:\Program Files\teamworkbackup>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=:"C:\Program files\teamworkdbackup\chromedriver.exe" -jar teamworkdbackup.jar
```

Source code:

```
package com.rhoads.teamwork.backup;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TeamworkBackup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver;

        String baseUrl;

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        baseUrl = "https://myco.teamwork.com/index.cfm";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("superstrong");
        driver.findElement(By.id("userLogin")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("userLogin")).sendKeys("someguy@example.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ordLoginSubmitBtn")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.get("https://myco.teamwork.com/settings?display=export");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.switchTo().frame("backupFrame");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Download")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.quit();


    }
}
```