# CasperJS/PhantomJS download CSV file

Tags: csv, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having trouble getting the contents of a CSV file that is being downloaded via CasperJs/PhantomJS.  The file download is being triggered via  link on the page being clicked and a resourceRecieved event is triggered and I can access the header/meta info for the file, but I can't get the content of the file which is what I need.

What does it take to get the content of a CSV file in CasperJS/PhantomJS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [casperjs download file without specifying url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461096/casperjs-download-file-without-specifying-url)

Comment: possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564215/how-to-download-a-csv-file-using-phantomjs/31910804?noredirect=1#comment51738263_31910804