# How to download file without url using casperjs

Tags: javascript, download, event-handling, casperjs

I am trying to download a csv file using casperjs but instead I get the code of the html page.

I cannot find the event handler so I don't know how to get the file! Below is the html code and is shown the image that when it is clicked, a csv file is downloaded. I searched in javascript files and I didn't find anything that is related with this image (eg a function that is called when the image is clicked)

```
<p align=right>
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ExportCSV" id="ctl00_ExportCSV" title="Export data to CSV file" src="images/csv.png" style="border-width:0px;" />
</p>
```

I tried the following code but without any success! :(

```
casper.on('resource.received', function(resource) {
   if (resource.stage !== "end") {
      console.log("resource.stage !== 'end'");
      return;
   }
   if (resource.url.indexOf('ExportData.csv') > -1) {
      console.log("Downloading csv file");
      var fs = require('fs');
      casper.download(resource.url, fs.workingDirectory+'/ExportData.csv');
   }
});
```

Any help how to download the file? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

First, `casper.download()` takes as its first 2 arguments 'String url' and 'String target.' 'String target' here is the name of the resource you wish to download, not the place where you wish to download it to, which is what I presume you interpreted it as since you used fs.workingDirectory as part of your 'String target.' See the example use of `casper.download()` [here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#download) and look at it closely.

Furthermore, it seems that in the html code you posted you are trying to download a .png file name csv.png, not an actual .csv file-- but that may be my misunderstanding. If you are trying to download a .png file, use `casper.captureSelector` as seen [here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector).

I believe you are trying to use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461096/casperjs-download-file-without-specifying-url) answer, so I have one final piece of advice to make your code work. It appears that you copy-pasted the code, so I have to make sure: the line `if (resource.url.indexOf('ExportData.csv') > -1) {` will only work if 'ExportData.csv' is in fact your resource's name. Use the line `console.log( resource.header )` to check the name of your resource. That name should also be your 'String target.'

I hope this helps!